# macOS autolayout - Wide text field constraints window size

Tags: swift, macos, autolayout, nstextfield

I have a text field inside a window. The text field is vertically centered in the window and has a left and right constraint set to 20.

[image]

The problem is, that I can't resize the window to have a smaller width than the text fields width, which is defined by the text inside it. What do I have to do to be able to make the window smaller and make the text field wrap the text inside? For example with "This is a very ver...".

Also if I specify a size for the window in interface builder, when I run the app the window will be bigger, when the text is too long. How can I prevent this and instead wrap the text of the text field?

Comment: are you sure about that it doesn't have also a width constraint?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I've just created a simple demo project to test it out. I've only added the vertical constraint and the two at the sides

Comment: What is Content Compression Resistance Priority?

Comment: I've actually never heard of this property. It's set to 750

Comment: Is the label a wrapping label?

Comment: The label is set to Truncate and in Line Break mode to Truncate Tail.

Comment: Tip: use the Wrapping Label aka Multi-line Label. It displays static text that line wraps as needed.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. That worked!